# Weird flickering in chrome on img:hover (transition opacity)

Tags: html, css

There is a weird flickering when I hover an `img` inside a row of a flexbox. When I turn `transition` off, the flickering disappears. What is happening and how can I fix it?

The bug is demonstrated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n9wL7par/
Try hovering the `imgs` of the middle row.

Turning off `transition` is not a solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#images {
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background: #000000;
}
    #images .col {
        width: 33.33333%;
        padding: 2px;
    }
        #images .col img {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            opacity: 0.8;
            transition: opacity .2s;
        }
            #images .col img:hover {
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 1;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
```

I've tried multiple things to solve it, but it doesn't work.
Safari does not have flickering so this is a Chrome related bug.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: It does filcker on the middle column, just a guess it is connected to the layout. What if you try to specify column width in pixels or at least set widths to 33-33-34?

Comment: Cannot see any flickering in my browser. Using chrome 48

Comment: Can you please elaborate what kind of flickering do you see? Am i missing something ?

Comment: Martin: That worked! Sooraj: Im using Version 48.0.2564.116

Comment: the flickering is in my browser is quite small, one or two pixels horizontally, version 48.0.2564.116.

Comment: Martin: There seems to be a problem with the calculation of 33.33%, perhaps depending on screen size? I've tried using a lot of decimals, but still flickering.

Comment: @Jakob yes, it looks it is connected to the percent and screen size. It looks like a bug imho.

Answer (score 0):

A weird bug indeed. I managed to solve it in your fiddle, by wrapping the image in another element, and applying the opacity transition to that.

```
<div class="inline-block">
    <img/>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Ah, I missed the display: inline-block